# I want to disable the options for each question saperately after clicking the option for that question

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
        setIsStarted(true)
        setCurrentScore(0)
        setResultCard(false)
        setCurrentQuestion(0)
    }   

    const checkOption = (isCorrect) =>{
        setDisability(true)
        if(isCorrect){
            setCurrentScore(currentScore+1);
        }
        setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion+1);

        if(currentQuestion==questions.length-1){
            setShowResult(true);
        }

    }

    function showResultButton(showResult){
        if (showResult) {
            return <button className='show-result' onClick={showResultCard}>Show results</button>
        }
    }

    const showResultCard = () =>{
        setShowResult(false)
        setResultCard(true);
        setIsStarted(false)
    }

    function displayResultCard(resultCard){
        
        if(resultCard){
            return <div className='score-card'>You have answerd {currentScore}/5 correctly</div>
        }
    }

    const updateDisability = () =>{
        setDisability(false)
    }

    function DisplayQuesion(){
        const quesList = questions.map((element) => {
            return(
                <div className='question-card'>
                    <h2>{element.text}</h2>
                    <ul>
                        {element.options.map((option) => {
                            return <button key={option.id} onClick={() => checkOption(option.isCorrect)} disabled={updateDisability}>{option.text}</button>
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return (<div>{quesList}</div>)
    }
```

In this code my all options are getting disabled even after clicking one option.When an option for a question is clicked, all other buttons for the question are disabled. when all questions are answered, the show results button gets shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're not splitting down the list of questions in child components and so on.
You need to create three components to achieve this:

1. Questionary
2. Question
3. Answer

By doing so, you'll be able to define a separate state for each question/answer so they don't get mixed up.

Within your code, notice that if you click on an item it will update the state of the entire component which consequentially will update also all the other answers because they shared the same state.

You can check this link to have a better understanding:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/passing-state-of-parent-to-child-component-as-props

Comment: Can you please elaborate and give code for this

Comment: Please refer to the link I shared with you. Working with components and their states is a must-know 'skill' if you're starting with React. Please use some time to study it instead of receiving it from someone. Take it as exercise! Just split everything into smaller components.

Comment: Try by creating first another component in a separate file called 'Question'. You can import it in your 'Questionary' components as <Question props={question.answers} /> and you can return it in your loop. Start by doing it step by step and not everything together, it will be easier